# Is it possible to have same resource names (for resw) in different directories?

Tags: localization, win-universal-app, embedded-resource

Normally, when you read about localization resources (RESW) for a universal application you are asked to create a single resource file for each language with Resource.resw name or in a most advanced scenario they advice to create two or three like Errors.resw, Messages.resw and that's about it. We have completely different approach (let's don't argue upon this, for us it proved to be good). We have a separate RESW file matching a CS file where we have resources which needs to be localized. We mimic the same folder structure in the Resource(language)\ folders as we have in the source code. The whole pattern came from Windows Phone Silverlight application and worked perfect with RESX. I have concerns regarding this in universal app. The problem is that even though a RESW file is located deep in the directory structure like

Res\it\Controls\Browser\MusicDetails.resw

it is referred as if it is located in the language root at Res\it. For example to get this resource in the code the code would look like this

resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView(currentAssemblyName + "/MusicDetails");
resourceLoader.GetString("Title");

Getting back to windows phone silverlight app the path in a similar case looks like "\Controls\Browser\MusicDetails.resw" and it is definitely not an issue for the RESX resources.

Is there something we are missing or it is a hard RESW limitation and all RESW files no matter where they are located in the directory structure are treated as if they are at the root of the language directory? I foresee a problem if in the future we have exactly the same RESW name in different directory branches. How to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible to do that, I tried to do something like you before with Windows 8.1 and it was not possible now with UWP is the same we need follow the guidelines  here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965328.aspx

I did this steps and it works like a charm.

UWP apps have restrictions they are not like traditional apps (Win32 apps)

Comment: Even in my case it works where I didn't follow the steps closely. The question is how to work around. I expected find something: a property in the csproj file on a RESW file which would tell makepri to do something differently or makepri parameters or build addons or something. Am I the only one who wants to maintain one RESW file for one localization target?